# Efficient way of counting number of elements smaller (larger) than cutoff in a sorted list

Tags: python

Let's assume we have a sorted list:

```
lst = [1,3,4,89,456,543] # a long one
```

and what we'd like to do is to find the number of elements in a list which are smaller than, `mx`.

Easy:

```
n = len([x for x in lst if x < mx])
```

or with generator:

```
n = sum(1 for x in lst if x < mx)
```

I assume the second approach should be slightly quicker, but still, the problem here is that we are going through all the elements of a list while we could stop early. It doesn't use the fact that the list is sorted.

Yep, I can do it with a loop:

```
s = 0
for x in lst:
    if x >= mx:
        break
    s += 1
```

But, I have a feeling there must be a better (shorter and / or quicker) way to do the same thing, maybe with some generator or an external module function?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We can do even better with a binary search, which is handily implemented for us in the [`bisect`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html) module:

```
import bisect
n = bisect.bisect_left(lst, mx)
```

This takes time logarithmic in the length of `lst`, whereas a linear search with early termination is linear in `n`. This will generally be faster.

If you want to use a linear search, the [`takewhile`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) function from [`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) can stop the iteration early:

```
import itertools
n = sum(1 for _ in itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x < mx, lst))
```

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to solve using binary search:

```
 #!/usr/bin/python

 lst = range(12, 100)
 mx = 30

 def binary_search(data, target, low, high):
     if low > high:
         return False
     else:
         mid = (low + high) // 2
         if target == data[mid]:
            return mid
         elif target < data[mid]:
            return binary_search(data, target, low, (mid - 1))
         else:
            return binary_search(data, target, mid + 1, high)

 if __name__ == '__main__':
     index = binary_search(lst, mx, 0, len(lst) + 1)
     print 'Count: %d' % len(lst[:index])
     print lst[:index]
```

Output:

```
Count : 18
[12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]
```